# can't find method result on TableQuery with slick 3.0.0-RC1

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying out Slick `3.0.0-RC1` and I'm running in to an odd problem.

Such is my code:

```
import slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

lazy val db = Database.forURL(
  url = "jdbc:sqlite:thebase.db",
  driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC"
)

case class Issue(id: Option[Int], name: String)     

class IssueTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Issue](tag, "issue"){
  def id = column[Int]("issue_id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (id.?, name) <> (Issue.tupled, Issue.unapply _)
}

val issueQuery = TableQuery[IssueTable]

Await.result(db.run(issueQuery.result), Duration.Inf) // This does not compile
```

The error is:

> "Cannot resolve symbol result"

Reading the [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-RC1/gettingstarted.html) I can't really see why this should fail. Am I missing something here?

**Resolution**

szeiger pointed out that this could be a bug in 'IntelliJ's presentation compiler', and that was spot on.

Comment: What does "compile" mean here? There is a known bug in IntelliJ's presentation compiler which prevents it from finding the method. The actual Scala compiler should be able to compile it.

Comment: You are right on the money. I never bothered to compile with sbt as IDEA gave me an error. Thanks!

Comment: Too bad IntelliJ doesn't get it. Ruins everything when using it for a large project where IDE is a must. Which is kinda the whole point - to get compile time checking and autocompletions

Comment: Nothing in https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala suggests that the method exists. Is it implemented with macros somehow? (forgive my ignorance if this doesn't make sense, I'm not experienced with macros)

Comment: For the reference, I believe that the issue link on the Jetbrains website is: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8079

Comment: Note for people encountering the same unresolved symptom "result": you may (as i did) have forgotten to import api

Comment: For me importing slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._ solved the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did hit the same problem and here is what I did to get rid of it:

1. Updated IntelliJ to version 14.1.3
2. Used Scala Plugin version 1.5

My scala version is 2.11.6

I hope this helps somebody who might run into the same problem!

Comment: Upgrading to the latest JetBrain Scala Plugin Version 1.5.2 fixed this for me

Answer (score 3):

If someone is facing a similar issue:

**no result method on TableQuery**

DOUBLE check whether you have `import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._`

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular problem I faced quite often with IntelliJ IDEA .

If using activator, the command - **"activator idea"** helped me resolve the issue.

It re-created the .idea and IdeaProject.iml files and then re-loaded the project. 
I currently use activator-1.3.4

Answer (score -4):

You may try

```
val result = db.withSession(implicit session => issueQuery.list)
```